# CoreDataGeneratedAccessors - removeObject does delete the object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

When I generate my classes from CoreData entities I get generated methods

```
@interface Site (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addSearchesObject:(Search *)value;
- (void)removeSearchesObject:(Search *)value;
- (void)addSearches:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeSearches:(NSSet *)value;

@end
```

So my question is pretty simple when I call removeSearchesObject:myObject do I have to delete it too ?

```
[site removeSearchesObject:[[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        [context deleteObject:[[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
```

Here is the generated code (from the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html))

```
- (void)removeEmployeesObject:(Employee *)value

{

    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];



    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"

          withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation

          usingObjects:changedObjects];

    [[self primitiveEmployees] removeObject:value];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"

          withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation

          usingObjects:changedObjects];



    [changedObjects release];

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, if you remove the object you still need to delete it. The system doesn't know if you are going to reattach it somewhere else. On the other hand, if you delete the object it will remove itself so long as the delete rule in your model is set to "Nullify." For more info you should check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) on delete rules.